# Is it possible to add item that the user enters into a jcombobox from the same jcombobox?

Tags: java, combobox

I am using Java in Netbeans and I have a combobox that allows the user to select an option on the list or enter their own option.
I know you can add an item to a combobox through a textfield, I wanted to know if there is a way that when the user enters their own option into the combobox and they click enter their option is added to the list.

I have tried

BusinessTypeComboBox.getItem(typeofBusiness);
   BusinessTypeComboBox.addItem(BusinessTypeComboBox.getText());

Does anyone know if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, the i would do it this way:

1. Add a KeyListener to the comboBox to know, when the user entered a new item and confirmed it.
2. Retrieve the list of items from the comboBox.

   ```
   ComboBoxModel model = comboBox.getModel();
   List list = new ArrayList();
   for(int i=0; i<model.getSize(); i++) {
       list.add(model.getElementAt(i));
   }
   ```
3. Append the entered item to the list.
4. Reinitialize the comboBox with the appended list.

   ```
   model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(list.toArray());
   comboBox.setModel(model);
   ```